# Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject

Tags: class, error, apex-email-service

I am finding it difficult to resolve the error. Any insights would be helpful. It is showing error for this line `String[] bccEmail = new String[]{opp.owner.email};` in the below code.

```
global class memberapproval2{

    webservice static boolean callApproval(Id localId) { 

         if(localId != null){

         List<opportunity> opp =[select id,owner.email,RSM_Shipping_Contact__c,RSM_Shipping_Contact__r.Email from opportunity where Id =:localId];


         if(opp.size()>0){

         List<String> EmailIds = new List<string>();
         if(opp[0].owner.email != null){
         EmailIds.add(opp[0].owner.email);
         }
         if(opp[0].RSM_Shipping_Contact__r.Email != null){
         EmailIds.add(opp[0].RSM_Shipping_Contact__r.Email);
         }

           //New instance of a single email message
             Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Who you are sending the email to

               mail.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
            String templateIdVal= Label.TemplateId;
            String[] bccEmail = new String[]{opp.owner.email};
               // The email template ID used for the email
               mail.setTemplateId(templateIdVal);
               mail.setTargetObjectId(userinfo.getuserid());      
               mail.setWhatId(localId);   

               mail.setBccSender(true);
               mail.setBccAddresses(bccEmail);
               mail.setUseSignature(false);
               mail.setReplyTo(opp.owner.email);
               mail.setSenderDisplayName('Confirmation of Order Quote');
               mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

         }

        return true;  
    }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`opp` is an array, and you're trying to use it like a single record.

You actually meant to write:

```
String[] bccEmail = new String[]{opp[0].owner.email};
```

Answer (score 3):

Its usually best to use plural names for collections and singular names for individual instances:

```
List<opportunity> opps = [select ... from opportunity where Id =:localId];
if(opps.size() > 0) {
    opportunity opp = opps[0];
    List<String> EmailIds = new List<string>();
    if (opp.owner.email != null) {
        ...
```

as its common to be dealing with both in code.